# How to create list of 2 from dataframe?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have transportation data between UK cities:

- from
- to
- Transit: if there is transit between these two cities =    1,
  otherwise =0
- weight: average number of passengers

Here is given sample from my data:

```
df2 <- data.frame (from  = c("London", "London", "London", "London" ,"Liverpool","Liverpool","Liverpool" , "Manchester", "Manchester", "Bristol"),
                  to = c("Liverpool", "Manchester", "Bristol","Derby", "Manchester", "Bristol","Derby","Bristol","Derby","Derby"),
                  Transit = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1),
                  ave.pas = c(10,0,11,24,40,45,12,34,9,29))
```

output

```
         from         to Transit weight
1      London  Liverpool       1     10
2      London Manchester       0      0
3      London    Bristol       1     11
4      London      Derby       1     24
5   Liverpool Manchester       1     40
6   Liverpool    Bristol       1     45
7   Liverpool      Derby       1     12
8  Manchester    Bristol       1     34
9  Manchester      Derby       0      9
10    Bristol      Derby       1     29
```

Now I want to convert it in the list of 2 to get data like this (this is different data but idea is to get the same from my df):

```
$nodes
# A tibble: 16 x 2
      id label         
   <int> <chr>         
 1     1 France        
 2     2 Belgium       
 3     3 Germany       
 4     4 Danemark      
 5     5 Croatia       
 6     6 Slovenia      
 7     7 Hungary       
 8     8 Spain         
 9     9 Italy         
10    10 Netherlands   
11    11 UK            
12    12 Austria       
13    13 Poland        
14    14 Switzerland   
15    15 Czech republic
16    16 Slovania      

$edges
# A tibble: 18 x 3
    from    to weight
   <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1     1     3    9  
 2     2     1    4  
 3     1     8    3  
 4     1     9    4  
 5     1    10    2  
 6     1    11    3  
 7     3    12    2  
 8     3    13    2  
 9     2     3    3  
10     3    14    2  
11     3    15    2  
12     3    10    2  
13     4     3    2  
14     5     3    2  
15     5    16    2  
16     5     7    2  
17     6     3    2  
18     7    16    2.5
```

Comment: You seem to have city names in your example data but then have country names in your desired output. Are those supposed to match? It would be better to give the exact desired output for the sample input you provide so possible solutions can be tested and verified to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create the dataframe of unique factor levels and create ids using `as.numeric`, then use `match` to replace the values with the id.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = as.numeric(factor(unique(unlist(df2[c(1,2)])), levels = unique(unlist(df2[c(1,2)])))),
                  label = factor(unique(unlist(df2[c(1,2)])), levels = unique(unlist(df2[c(1,2)]))))
#  id      label
#1  1     London
#2  2  Liverpool
#3  3 Manchester
#4  4    Bristol
#5  5      Derby

df2$from <- df1$id[match(df2$from, df1$label)]
df2$to <- df1$id[match(df2$to, df1$label)]
#   from to Transit ave.pas
#1     1  2       1      10
#2     1  3       0       0
#3     1  4       1      11
#4     1  5       1      24
#5     2  3       1      40
#6     2  4       1      45
#7     2  5       1      12
#8     3  4       1      34
#9     3  5       0       9
#10    4  5       1      29
```

---

Edit: you actually don't need to convert to factor (this comes then very close to @sindri_baldur's answer):

```r
un <- unique(unlist(df2[c(1, 2)]))
df1 <- data.frame(id = seq_along(un), label = un)
df2[c(1, 2)] <- sapply(df2[c(1, 2)], match, df1$label)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300531/how-to-plot-circular-network-in-r#72300531

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```r
f2 = c('from', 'to')

nodes     = data.frame(label = unique(unlist(df2[f2])))
nodes$id  = seq_len(nrow(nodes)) 
edges     = df2[df2$Transit == 1, c(f2, 'ave.pas')]
edges[f2] = lapply(edges[f2], match, nodes$label)
```

```r
nodes
#        label id
# 1     London  1
# 2  Liverpool  2
# 3 Manchester  3
# 4    Bristol  4
# 5      Derby  5

edges
#    from to ave.pas
# 1     1  2      10
# 3     1  4      11
# 4     1  5      24
# 5     2  3      40
# 6     2  4      45
# 7     2  5      12
# 8     3  4      34
# 10    4  5      29
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300531/how-to-plot-circular-network-in-r#72300531